# Not a Valid Month - Working with Dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am finding it strenuous to work with dates in my customized environment. I have a request to add a where clause which caters to specific dates but I just cannot get oracle to budge. Any ideas anyone please.

```
 select created_date, cast(created_date as date) as created_date_cast
   from mytable;

 created_date                                  created_date_cast
 04-Mar-20 05.21.15.772000 AM                  3/4/2020 5:21:15 AM
 04-Mar-20 05.21.15.709000 AM                  3/4/2020 5:21:15 AM
 04-Mar-20 05.17.14.902000 AM                  3/4/2020 5:14:14 AM
 28-Feb-20 01.15.25.702700 AM                  2/28/2020 1:15:25 AM
```

When I try to add a `where` clause the snippet blows up with the error:

```
select created_date, cast(created_date as date) as created_date_cast
  from mytable
 where cast(created_date as date) <= '02/28/2020';

ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

I have also tried `to_date(created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` in the from but proves to be erroneous with:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `created_date`?

Comment: I think its `timestamp`.

Comment: What means "I think"? Please verify as it it most likely the reason for your problem.

Comment: just use `trunc()` function as `trunc(created_date) <= date'2020-02-28'`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, it is `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly cast as date which converts a timestamp value to a date value, and then don't forget to add `trunc()` function in order to include the boundry value (`date'2020-02-28'` in this case) also as

```
where trunc(cast(created_date as date)) <= date'2020-02-28'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=30d6c07c780268012978ae2ed4ea3b1d)</kbd>

Comment: Simply Spectacular. Thanks Barbaros!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `CAST` and don't use `TRUNC` (as then Oracle will not be able to use an index on your column but would, instead, require a function-based index created on `TRUNC(created_date)`) just add a day and use a literal:

```sql
SELECT created_date
FROM   mytable
WHERE  created_date < DATE '2020-02-29';
```

or

```sql
SELECT created_date
FROM   mytable
WHERE  created_date < TIMESTAMP '2020-02-29 00:00:00';
```

or, if you want to specify the exact date then just add a day. E.g.:

```sql
SELECT created_date
FROM   mytable
WHERE  created_date < DATE '2020-02-28' + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

All of those options should be able to use an index on the `created_date` column.

> I have also tried `to_date(created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` in the from but proves to be erroneous with:
>
> ```sql
> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
> ```

`TO_DATE( value_string, format_model )` takes strings as its arguments but `CREATED_DATE` is a `TIMESTAMP` data type and not a string so Oracle must make an implicit `TIMESTAMP`-to-string conversion and it does this using the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` session parameter; so your expression is effectively:

```sql
TO_DATE(
  TO_CHAR(
    created_date,
    ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT' )
  ),
  'MM/DD/YYYY'
)
```

And if your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` is not `MM/DD/YYYY` then its highly likely that an exception will be raised (i.e. like the `ORA-01858` you had).

You should never rely on implicit string conversions as any user can change their own session parameters at any time and an implicit conversion that works for one user may not work for another just because they have different parameter values (even though the queries are identical).

Answer (score 0):

Use a date literal:

```
cast(created_date as date) <= date '2020-02-28'
```

I would also recommend dispensing with the `cast()` -- assuming that `created_date` is correctly stored as a `date` or `timestamp`:

```
created_date < (date '2020-02-28' + interval '1' day)
```

Comment: No Dice @ Gordon, it still spills the same `ORA-01858`.

Comment: @JakeWagner . . . Are you suggesting that `created_date` is stored as something other than a `date` or `timestamp`?

Comment: Its `TimeStamp`.